# www to non-www redirect issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have figured out how to get all of my pages from **example.com** to **www.example.com**, but any code I find isn't working to do the exact opposite. I need to go from **www.example.com** to **example.com**.

Here is the code I have. Can someone help me rewrite it so that it does the opposite? Any edits I make either 404 or infinite loop.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L,R=301,NE]
```

-----EDIT-----

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

-----EDIT 2-----

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

Options +MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php [L]
```

I went with `Options +MultiViews` because what you gave me was `Options -MultiViews` and it always took me to the "Not Found, here are similar files" page.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

---

EDIT:

To avoid conflicts with mod_negotiation, try adding this *after* the above rules:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php [L]
```

Comment: Okay, that's mostly working. The problem I'm having is that, with this code, **www.example.com/test** is becoming **example.com/test.php** . I want to get rid of the .php, any advice on how to do that? Any other code I install in the .htaccess doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @RichardColeman Do you have other rules? If so, make sure the redirect is **before** any other rewrite rules you may have. Also, make sure you have `MultiViews` turned off.

Comment: There are no other rules. As of now, my code consists of what I've edited the original post to add.

I'm assuming that `Options +MultiViews` is the correct option, as `Options -MultiViews` actually takes me to the "we couldn't find that page but here are similar results" page.

Comment: @RichardColeman The reason why you're getting redirected to `test.php` is because the URI `/test` is getting processed by 2 modules (mod_negotiation and mod_rewrite) as it makes its way through the URL/file mapping pipeline. Because of that, mod_negotiation changes the request to `/test.php`, and when mod_rewrite gets to it, it uses the changed URI when it redirects. You can try turning off `Multiviews` and do the php mapping within mod_rewrite. (See edit)

Comment: Okay, I added those lines, unfortunately, nothing has changed (still getting to test.php). Under "EDIT 2" above is my .htaccess file as it looks now. I appreciate all your help! I just can't figure out why what seems to be working for everyone else isn't working for me :/

Comment: `MultiViews` seems to be doing the opposite of what it's supposed to be doing. I turned off MultiViews with `Options -MultiViews`, and I get this 300 Multiple Choices page on my site: http://kineticparkour.com/test

Comment: @RichardColeman See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html Do you have any *.var files? Can you prevent mod_negotiation from loading in server config?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have that much control over the server; it's a shared 1and1 hosting server. No httpd access. Does this mean this is effectively out of my reach?